# R bookdown multiple authors LaTeX Error: Counter too large

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to add all authors of a paper in the YAML of a .Rmd file.
In bookdown::html_document2 it works fine.
In bookdown::pdf_book it gives `! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.`

Here is the YAML :

```
---
title: "Supplementary material"
subtitle: "Article title"
author:
- Author One^[A, email@univ.com]
- Author Two^[A]
- Author Three^[B]
- Author Four^[C, D]
- Author Five^[D]
- Author Six^[A]
- Author Seven^[D]
- Author Eight^[D]
- Author Nine^[E]
- Author Ten^[A]
- Author Eleven^[F, G, H]
- Author Twelve^[A]
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
bibliography: "`r here::here('References.bib')`"
csl: "`r here::here('style.csl')`"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{chngcntr}
  - \counterwithin{figure}{section}
always_allow_html: true
---
```

There might be another way to do it but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: When doing a less elegant solution without involving footnotes (e.g. ```- Author One(A, email@univ.com)``` and putting what is A as the first text of the document), there is not error but it is not very pretty and the table of contents arrives before the text, which is not optimal.